# Vaadin - How add checkbox component to a tree?

Tags: checkbox, tree, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 7.5.3 to develop a web application. There I need a tree with selectable nodes. I want to select nodes using checkboxes. After trying many ways and goggling, I could not find how to add CheckBox component to a tree node.

Comment: What have you so far? (Have you tried in the tree editable mode)?

Comment: What do you mean by editable mode? Do you mean `tree.setReadOnly(false)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my knowledge, up to the current latest version aka Vaadin 7.5.6, this is not possible, as Jouni point out in this [discussion on their forums](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/19727/18555). He has also opened [an improvement ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/2661) but I don't see any changes so far.

Nonetheless, you should be able to *fake* it by using the [TreeTable component](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#component.treetable.components). You can find [here](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/trunk/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/TreeTableExample.java) a complete example, and below an excerpt from it:

```
final TreeTable ttable = new TreeTable("My TreeTable");
ttable.addContainerProperty("Name", CheckBox.class, "");
ttable.addContainerProperty("City", String.class, "");
ttable.setWidth("20em");

// Create the tree nodes
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Root"), "Helsinki"}, 0);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Branch 1"), "Tampere"}, 1);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Branch 2"), "Turku"}, 2);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Leaf 1"), "Piikkiö"}, 3);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Leaf 2"), "Parainen"}, 4);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Leaf 3"), "Raisio"}, 5);
ttable.addItem(new Object[]{new CheckBox("Leaf 4"), "Naantali"}, 6);

// Set the hierarchy
ttable.setParent(1, 0);
ttable.setParent(2, 0);
ttable.setParent(3, 1);
ttable.setParent(4, 1);
ttable.setParent(5, 2);
ttable.setParent(6, 2);

// Expand the tree
ttable.setCollapsed(2, false);
for (Object itemId: ttable.getItemIds())
    ttable.setCollapsed(itemId, false);

ttable.setPageLength(ttable.size());
```

And this is the output

[image: checkbox in tree]

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so for what it's worth: the Vaadin demo page has an example of exactly this:

http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book#component.tree.itemstylegenerato

Comment: https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/TreeExample.java

Comment: Why not to use TreeGrid?

Comment: @Alex78191 that didn't exist at the time